# fdisk partition "n megabytes" less than total physical size

Tags: linux, raid, fdisk

Is there a way to use fdisk to define a new partition that is e.g. "100MB less" than the maximum possible size?

Background:
Due to deviation between nominal disk size and physical disk size, and the necessity to replace a failed raid unit with one of equivalent size, it is [recommended to build an `mdadm` array over partitions slightly smaller than the physical disk size](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID).

Comment: Yes, there's a way. When `fdisk` asks for the last sector for the partition, you calculate and provide a value that results in the desired size. Do you need guidance on how to calculate? Or do you mean "automatically"? i.e. without manual calculation? Does it have to be with `fdisk`?

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski, if you want to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.  I posted a sample formulation below for convenience

Comment: I don't want to. I commented because it wasn't clear what guidance you wanted. I wasn't aware one can specify `-100M`; I knew about `+100M` and such. It probably depends on `fdisk` implementation or version. E.g. `fdisk` in my Kubuntu operates on sectors, not cylinders; and it *doesn't* understand `-100M`. I usually use a calculator, `dc` or `bc` (or a pencil and a piece of paper) to get the *exact* number for the last sector.

Answer (score 0):

The following is derived from an example I found this tutorial in [TLDP-Partitioning with fdisk](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html):

```
Command (m for help): n
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4): 1
First cylinder (1-621, default 1):<RETURN>
Using default value 1
Last cylinder or +size or +sizeM or +sizeK (1-621, default 621): -100M
```

Please note (as commented by @KamilMaciorowski) that fdisk may have multiple implementations that don't support this size-based positioning.